# I wanted to setup back face culling for my sphere object but i am struck at defining the vertices for my wire frame sphere object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a sphere object in wireframe but I am stuck when I want to define vertices and apply the [back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) for the created wireframe sphere object.
   Can anyone please help? And how to define vertices for a wireframe sphere object?

My HTML file: here I am using [three.js](http://threejs.org/) library as I am new to [WebGL](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/) I was unable to do something with this problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Construct a sphere model in WebGL </title>
        <script src ="./three.js-master/three.js-master/build/three.js"></script>
        <script src ="./three.js-master/three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Three.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="createsphere()">
        <canvas id="glcanvas" width="840" height="620"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Three.js is my javascript file linked.

```
function createsphere() {
    var pos = function(d) { return document.getElementById(d); };

    //def scene, camera, renderer
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);  
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //creating a sphere object

    var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0, 30, 30);
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('earth.jpg', {}, function() { alert('texture loaded');}, function(){ alert('error loading texture');});
    var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true, map: texture});
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, spherematerial);

    scene.add(sphere); 

    camera.position.z = 5;

    //renderer
    var render = function(e) {
        requestAnimationFrame(render); 
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please provide more details? Screenshot, error stack trace, etc.

Comment: As I suppose, you are using [three.js](http://threejs.org) library and asking about [MeshBasicMaterial](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshBasicMaterial). Please include it into your question also. There are a lot of people that can help you and they shouldn't spend their time guessing important details.

Comment: yes i am using three.js library and here i am adding my html file too

Comment: i think i have posted all the information which i have...

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is no back-face culling when doing wireframe since there is no *faces* strictly speaking, only lines.

Maybe what you should do is to create two meshes, one with the wireframe material, and one, smaller and black, inside the first one,0 Like so

```
function createsphere() {
    var pos = function(d) { return document.getElementById(d); };

    //def scene, camera, renderer
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    //creating a sphere object

    var spheregeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1.0, 30, 30);
    var spheregeometry2 = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.99, 30, 30);
    var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('earth.jpg', {}, function() { alert('texture loaded');}, function(){ alert('error loading texture');});

    var spherematerial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true});
    var spherematerial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({side : THREE.DoubleSide, color : '#000000'});

    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry, spherematerial);
    var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(spheregeometry2, spherematerial2);

    scene.add(sphere);
    scene.add(sphere2);

    camera.position.z = 0;

    //renderer
    var render = function(e) {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };

    render();
}
```

Note that this solution implies that once you're in the inside of the sphere, you will not be able to see the outside.

If you want to see the outside, then, I don't think you can make this work using the `wireframe` attribute of `MeshBasicMaterial`. Maybe you will need to write a shader that would render the wire over the texture of the sphere.

Comment: @sravan Check my edit, and tell me if it's what you need please !

Comment: @DragonRock.....thank you for your response i have tried your edit its working fine but i have one more challenge can it be possible to set the TRIANGLE_STRIP for this code. I tried to find out but nothing was so clear..

Comment: What do you mean by *triangle strip * ? The wireframe mesh is showing triangles right ? Do you want to have a different display or... ?

Comment: yes...like i would like to remove out the wireframe and want to set up the TRIANGLE_STRIP on the sphere...

Comment: Well, if you want to remove the wireframe, you could just set the `wireframe` option to false on the material. But I can't see what you mean by *triangle strip*. To me, *triangle strip* is just a compressed way to draw triangles, it has no impact on the display of the model. You're sure you're talking about *triangle strip* ?

Comment: yes i need to setup the compressed way which you are talking about and i am sure about triangle_strip.. it doesn't matter whether it has an impact on my display or not..can you please help me how can i do that...?

Comment: The thing is that I don't really see why you would want to have a *triangle strip* here... However, if you want to do this, I'm not sure you'll be able to do it with `THREE.js`, there seemed to be someone who wanted to implement this, but I don't think it was done...